# Import data from files of LIST extension

Tags: mysql, database, file

I have to use raw data available in .LIST extension files and I have to import this data to much usable format like to MySql or excel.

Can anyone let me know how can I extract raw data from .LIST files. How can I parse the data in a .LIST file and probably export it to excel or MySql?

Comment: What is the input format, exactly? What should the output format be? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, its raw data in .LIST extension files. Here is my data source - http://www.imdb.com/interfaces#plain . I don't see any particular input format, each input file is different. Output format, I would prefer a relational database like mySql. I am on the verge of writing an app with customization for each input file using regex perhaps to parse and import data to MySql. I want to know if there is any other method to extract data from .LIST files that I am not aware of and if its less laborious..

Comment: Looking at two of the files in there, I see that the format of the lists themselves is the same: list items start with a `#` and then goes a description starting with a `-`. This is basically plaintext, I don't think it even needs regex. For filling a DB look at [`SQLAlchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or maybe [`MySQLdb`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found that there is no generic way of parsing a .list file as it could have any textual information but the .list files that I was particularly interested in were from [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) and I found a python script, [imdbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/), that parses and imports data from the .list files to any relational db such as mysql, MSSQL etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use .csv files. If yes then just open your data file in excel and save it as .csv format. If you have MySql workbench then life is easy. You have to just click on a button tooltiped "Import data from an external file".